# How to get jQuery UI datepicker to work correctly in a form that's loaded via ajax request

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I have a calendar page and for each day, I have a link that loads a form via ajax into a bootstrap popover. In that ajax form, I have a start date field and an end date field. Immediately after loading the form and then creating and showing the popover, I'm using jQuery to add datepicker to each of the date fields via jQuery:

```
$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({ changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy" }); //add the datepicker
```

It's clearly successfully binding the datepicker to the fields because when I click on either of these fields, the datepicker appears.

However, when I select a date, I'm getting the following error in the console:

```
[Error] TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating '= inst.currentDay = $("a", td).html()')
_selectDay (jquery.ui.datepicker.js, line 977)
selectDay (jquery.ui.datepicker.js, line 1568)
dispatch (jquery.js, line 5096)
handle (jquery.js, line 4767)
```

I've been reading a lot about this, and it seems that this is because the input field I'm binding datepicker to was loaded as part of an ajax request after the DOM initially loaded. That makes sense, because I use the exact same method to bind the datepicker on other pages, but on those other pages the form elements to which I'm attaching the datepicker were part of the initial page load. In those pages, everything works just fine.

So, is it correct that I'm getting this problem because the form with the input is loaded asynchronously? And if so, what can I do to properly use the datepicker on form elements loaded in this manner?

**Update**

Here are some details on exactly how I'm doing it presently. As per @Mandeep, I'm doing this the rails way. Here is the code (`new.js.erb`) that builds the popover and then subsequently adds the datepicker:

```
$('#newEvent').empty(); //empty any previous popover content from its container
$('#<%= @event.start.to_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") %>').find('a.new-event-link').popover('destroy'); //destroy any popover currently bound to the link
$('#<%= @event.start.to_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") %>').find('a.new-event-link').popover({ 
    trigger:'manual', placement: 'left', html:true, title:'New Event', content:'<%= j render("new_popover") %>', container:"#newEvent"
}); //create the popover and render _new_popover.html.erb in the contents. This is the form with the dates
$('#<%= @event.start.to_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") %>').find('a.new-event-link').popover('show'); //show the popover
$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({ changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy" }); //add the datepicker
$('#cancelEvent').click(function(){
    $('#<%= @event.start.to_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") %>').find('a.new-event-link').popover('hide');
}); //hide the popover on clicking cancel
```

As mentioned, this all works correctly to 1) create the popover and render the form in it, and 2) attach the datepicker. But the problem comes on selecting the date. That's when I get the error.

Comment: Have you tried enabling datepicker on the element after it's appended to the dom instead of on ready?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I'm a dork. It had nothing inherently to do with the ajax request. Rather, the problem was that the original page used a form with hidden fields (many in fact -- one for each day in the calendar) the submission of which generated the ajax popover form. Those hidden fields let rails know the date for which it should pre-populate the ajax form. And as it turns out, those hidden fields shared the same id as the date inputs in the ajax form. That was throwing off the datepicker. I changed the way I build the request form somewhat so that it doesn't use the same id. Now everything works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest putting the datepicker assignment inside your HTML that your getting from the AJAX call.
That's how I do it and it works for me.
I know it's a little bit messier, but simply adding:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({ changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy" }); //add the datepicker
</script>
```

to the end of the HTML that you're retrieving should do the trick.
It's possible that tacking that on the returned data in the javascript side of things (BEFORE adding the content to the webpage) might work too, I've simply not tried that.

Let me know if you struggle and I'll provide code samples.

Comment: Tried this instead of my current method (I'll update with more details above), and I still get the same result: Datepicker successfully binds to the input field (I get the datepicker when I click on the field), but selecting a date generates the error above.

Answer (score 0):

In order to keep Javascript out of HTML page (a good practice), you can do it like this in a separate Javascript file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("focus", "[class~='datepicker']", function(e){
    $(this).datepicker({ changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy" }); //add the datepicker
  });
});
```

This is how I do it in my projects.

Comment: Tried this instead of my current method (adding details above). Still generates same result: datepicker appears properly when clicking on the field (so it's been successfully attached), but clicking on a date generates the same error. I'm assuming the intent here is to have the run the ready function every time the document successfully completes an update? As I say, it works well to bind the datepicker, but it's selecting a date that generates the error.

Comment: Could you please share the HTML content of popover. It might help in debugging this issue.

Comment: Figured it out. It was a stupid `id` conflict. I posted the answer above. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

a. **Call your js after your form is loaded by ajax** request. If you are using rails way of doing ajax then inside your **method.js.erb**(here method will be your controller method used to call ajax request) you can write this at bottom

```
$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({ changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy" }); //add the datepicker
```

b. You can use **Jquery `live` or [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) event** handler and place your js code in application.js or some other js file and require that file in application.js

```
$(document).on("click",".datepicker",function(e){
  $(this)..datepicker({ changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy" }); //add the datepicker
  e.preventDefault();
});
```